# TinyMCE Value Returns NULL/ no value on the first submit

Tags: php, forms, tinymce

I'm new in the `TinyMCE`...and I'm still wondering about this problem

I have form which loaded dynamically from 1 page. And the form has tinyMCE textarea on it.
And on the first submit after I put some values on the text area, the value of the textarea is not received by `$_REQUEST['Sub-Headline']`. I have to click the submit button again, and sometimes I need to re-open the form in order for the value to be received by `$_REQUEST['Sub-Headline'];`

Can you guys suggest me what I need to check and what options/other things that I should add?

Here is part of code of the form :

**TinyMCE**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
            mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
            theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,undo,redo",        
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        convert_urls : false,
        plugins : "legacyoutput"
    });
</script>
```

**FORM**

```
    <form action="web-block/forms/process-001.php" id="Frm001" method="post" class="general-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="input-wrap">
        <input class="clearme" name="Headline" value="<?php echo $Headline;?>" id="headline"/>
    </div>

    <div class="input-wrap">
    <textarea class="clearme" name="Sub-Headline" id="subheadline"><?php echo $SubHeadline;?></textarea>
    </div>

<label>Main Image</label>
<div class="up-mask">
    <span class="file-wrapper">
      <input type="file" name="pics" class="photo" id="pics" />
      <span class="button">
         <span class="default-txt">Upload Photo (Max Size 300Kb, 960x567 pixels)</span>
      </span>
    </span>
</div><!-- .up-mask -->

<input type="hidden" name="Key" id="Key" value="<?php echo urlencode($Key);?>"/>
<input type="submit" class="submit-btn" value="Save" />
<a href="#" id="reset">Reset</a>
<span class="save-notice"></span>
</form>
```

**SUBMIT CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
        beforeSubmit: function() {
            alert("kuntul");
            tinyMCE.triggerSave();
        },
        success: function() {
            $('span.save-notice').text('Save Changed Successfully');
            $('span.save-notice').show(2000);
                $('span.save-notice').hide(2000);
        }
    };
    $('#Frm001').submit(function() { 
            $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
            return false; 
        });
});      
</script>
```

Comment: Is it contained in `$_POST['Sub-Headline']`?

Comment: Yes, it is. I need to submit 2x to make the forms work

Answer (score 3):

You will have to call `tinymce.triggerSave()` before you submit the form.

Comment: Yep, I already use it. 
I just add my form submission code on this discussion. Do I put it in the wrong way?

Comment: hmm, not sure. i would call it right before calling $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);

Answer (score 0):

Please place your javascript code below your html code. It should work..

HTML CODE GOES HERE..............

Script Below..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
            mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
            theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,undo,redo",        
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        convert_urls : false,
        plugins : "legacyoutput"
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you mean if the tinyMCE should be put on the bottom of the HTML Form Code? Nope...Still doesn't work in my case...